# File update statistics

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, folder, file, web-analytics

We have a workflow, where business users have to update the data in SharePoint every day.

Is there a way to monitor it easily and smart way? Currently I am clicking each folder to the file and I have 30 files and growing.

I tried to explore the Power Apps, they have lot of Power Apps for file modified which I can use in negative terms but every few seconds or minutes users update the file, I will lose it which file when. Also they are not free, and there is no budget.

I have about 30 folders inside a main folder and each folder has a set of files, one spread sheet per folder is where I am keen to know last modified date easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here's full PowerShell for retrieving all folder, sub-folder and files with last modified date for your reference.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$SiteURL="site collection URL"
$UserName="emily@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "xxx"
$listName ="document library name"

$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)

#Bind to Site Collection
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = $Creds

$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$q = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$q.ViewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query></Query></View>'
$items = $list.GetItems($q)
$ctx.Load($items)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($item in $items)
{
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "Name: " $item["FileLeafRef"] ----"Last Modified Time: " $item["Modified"]
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Emily Du,

Thank you very much indeed. But please can you confirm, this script needs to be executed on the SharePoint server. I have a SharePoint client running on my desktop and have no access to the server. 
I do not seem to have this file access 
1. Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
2. Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Please advise.
Best Regards